# How can I use PHP string var inside another one? ($org was supposed to be 'BUR')

Tags: php, informix, fatal-error

I'm trying to run a query; to make the string that has the query, I need to concatenate $org and $calendar . I have tried this:

```
$cal = $org.$year; //$org = 'COM', $year= '2021'
$condition = "coba.calendar LIKE '$cal%' "; //So it should be like "coba.calendar LIKE 'COM2021%'

$qry = "SELECT coba.field_1, coba.field_2
FROM table_1 coba
WHERE $condition";
```

And then run the $qry, but I'm getting a Fatal error: Allowed memory size of...

```
$rs = odbc_exec($link_ifx, $qry); //I'm getting a Fatal error: Allowed memory size of...
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($ )) {
  $array[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

But if I do this it works:

```
$qry = "SELECT coba.field_1, coba.field_2
FROM table_1 coba
WHERE coba.calendar LIKE 'COM2021%'";
```

I've found that I was using other string for $org, I was using 'BUR' originally instead of 'COM' as I thought I was.

coba.field_1 was `CAST(substr(padt.paquete,4,length(padt.paquete)) AS INT) nu_paquete` and while using it with $org = 'BUR' it didn't have NULLS but with 'COM' it had. And that was causing a Fatal error: Allowed memory.

Comment: It should work the same as when you write the query as a literal. What do you see if you do `var_dump($qry);`?

Comment: I see what the $qry has. `SELECT coba.field_1, coba.field_2 FROM table_1 coba WHERE coba.calendar LIKE 'COM2021%'`

Comment: Then there's no reason why one should work and the other gets an error. It doesn't matter how you create the `$qry` string.

Comment: BTW, your code is open to SQL injection. You should use a prepared statement instead of substituting variables directly into the SQL.

Comment: Try this $qry2 = $qry; $rs = odbc_exec($link_ifx, $qry2);

Comment: Have you printed the query or condition (`$qry` or `$condition`) to see whether you get what you expect?